# SQL Query to fetch data based on the date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data  which has index and date  I need to perform logic in which I need to compare the first date with next date if the date range is lesser than 31 remove the second, again compare the first with third if it's greater than 31 keep the first and third and compare the third with fourth if less remove or if greater add keep on like this. Can anyone help me out on this logic

Simply first record should be compared with prior records with greater of 31

```
index     DATE
1     2020-01-01
1     2020-01-15
1     2020-01-30
1     2020-02-02
1     2020-02-20
1     2020-03-05
1     2020-03-25
2     2020-04-30
```

**Required output**

```
index     DATE
1     2020-01-01
1     2020-02-02
1     2020-03-05
2     2020-04-30
```

Comment: What version of MySQL? If you have 8.x you can use window functions like `LAG()`

Comment: @Barmar.. I'm extremely it's sql server

Comment: In that case you should be able to use window functions even with old versions.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original question which was tagged MySQL.

You need to use a recursive CTE for this type of operation:

```
with recursive cte(ind, date) as (
      select ind, min(date) as date
      from t
      group by ind
      union all
      select cte.ind,
             (select min(t2.date)
              from t t2
              where t2.ind = cte.ind and t2.date > cte.date + interval 30 day
             )
      from cte
      where exists (select 1
                    from t t2
                    where t2.ind = cte.ind and t2.date > cte.date + interval 30 day
                   )
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bca5aeb962054fd0f4e8ca48a455d1af) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @gordon I need it on sql not on mysql

Comment: @Shuail_CR007 . . . I would suggest you ask a new question.  The answers are different in the two databases, and I don't usually revise my answers when questions change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query

```
create table indextbl(indexid int, dt date)
insert into indextbl values(1,     '2020-01-01')
,(1,'2020-01-15')
,(1,'2020-01-30')
,(1,'2020-02-02')
,(1,'2020-02-20')
,(1,'2020-03-05')
,(1,'2020-03-25')
,(2,'2020-04-30')

select indexid, MIN(dt) from indextbl
group by indexid, LEFT(dt,7)
```

Comment: This works fine absolutely.. But a condition fails when I add 2020-05-05.to next... As per my above description it should have 31days of gap.. Not the min dt in month